# How to close frame within applet?

Tags: java, applet, awt, frame, accesscontrolexception

Guys am trying to close frame within applet... my program is working but the problem is that the frame which will get created within applet is not closing... what should i do...
it gives me Exception while closing frame window:

```
C:\jdk1.6.0\bin>appletviewer me.java                                            
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission exitVM.0)                                       at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:323)                                                         at
java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:546)
```

Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
/*<applet code="me.class" height=500 width=500></applet>*/
class se extends Frame {

    String msg;

    public se() {
        msg="This is Frame";
        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawString(msg,10,100);
    }
}

public class me extends Applet {

    public void init() {
        se s1=new se();
        s1.setSize(400,400);
        s1.setVisible(true);
        s1.setTitle("The JAVA GAMER");
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawString("This is Applet",10,100);
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) Why code an applet?  If it is due to spec. by teacher, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 2) Why AWT rather than Swing?  See my answer on [Swing extras over AWT](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6255978/418556) for many good reasons to abandon using AWT components.

Comment: Answer my questions..

Answer (score 1):

```
System.exit(0);
```

This is not permitted by the applet sand-box, *even if the applet is fully trusted.*

But better to make this a stand-along app. (`Frame`/`JFrame`) & deploy it from a link/button on a web page using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  JWS works on Windows, OS X & *nix.  Then the frame can call `System.exit(n)` at any security level.